# sns.Facetgrid not showing normal disttribution line and ignoring space warning

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a `Facetgrid` with seaborn to show all my columns distribution along with a normal distribution line to compare to the normal.

My dataFrame in `pandas` looks as such:

```
     column  values
0     P100m     938
0       Plj    1061
0       Psp     773
0       Phj     859
0     P400m     896
 ...     ...
7967  P110h     741
7967    Ppv     804
7967    Pdt     527
7967    Pjt     738
7967  P1500     523
```

I have added a parameter to the `sns.Facetgrid` which should space the plots so they do not clash. Preferably I would have them next to each other instead of all stacked. My `bins` argument has also been ignored and there are clearly not 20 there.

My normal line is also not appearing despite me having the parameter `density=True` in the plot.
This is both my code and the output graph I am receiving:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_stacked, row = 'column', gridspec_kws={"wspace":0.4})
g = g.map(plt.hist, "values", stacked=True, bins = 20, density= True)
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_stacked,col='column',col_wrap=3)
g = g.map(sns.distplot, 'values',bins=20)
```

I generated some random data to fill out the DataFrame like so:

```
import random
l = ['P100m', 'Plj', 'Psp', 'Phj', 'P400m', 'P110h', 'Ppv', 'Pdt', 'Pjt', 'P1500']
ints = [random.randint(500,1100) for i in range(7000)] 
df_stacked = pd.DataFrame({'column':l*700,'values':ints})
```

This will produce something like:
[image]
Note: I wasn't able to specify a "wspace" value that would give enough space so I left that out.

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding to you